# positioning at right with vertically centered text also rotated text 90 degree with <img><i> blocked

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap

I have been trying to add a column of `<img-top right-aligned>  [<p-rotated 90 degree><i star symbol>*5(arranged vertically)]`

you may not under stand the above line i will add a screenshot of what am looking for below
[image: This is output am looking for]

[image: So far i have completed till this]

but I'm struggling in the part I have circled.I need google review text and 5 star font awesome symbols to be vertically centered in the right.

```css
.contact-card {
    background-color: #88206D;
    border: solid 2px #fff;
    border-radius: 21px;
    min-height: 406px;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}


  #google-icon img {

      height: 44px;
      z-index: 1000;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 22px;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.53);
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.53);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.53);

  }

  .google-review {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<main>
        <div class="container">              
            <div class="row contact-card">  
                <div class="map col-5" id="map"></div>
                <div class="offset-2 image-scroll"></div>
                <div class="map-des col-3 text-white my-auto pt-4" id="m-des"></div>
                    
<!-- i struggle in this part -- >

                <!-- google reviews -->
                <div class="col-1 text-center">
                  <div id="google-icon">
                  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nknMt4k/search.png" class="google-icon">    
                </div>  
                  
    
                  <div class="side-star">
                  <p class="google-review text-nowrap">
                    <strong>Google Review</strong>
                  </p>
                  <div class="five-star d-flex flex-column">
                    
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                  
                  
                  
                  </div>
                </div></div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this may help you: https://dev.to/afif/how-to-correctly-position-rotated-text-using-css-1gjc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: flex` and `align-items: center` :

```css
.contact-card {
    background-color: #88206D;
    border: solid 2px #fff;
    border-radius: 21px;
    min-height: 406px;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}


  #google-icon img {

      height: 44px;
      z-index: 1000;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 22px;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.53);
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.53);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.53);
     margin-top: 24px;
     margin-bottom: 60px;
  }

  .google-review {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }

.col-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<main>
        <div class="container">              
            <div class="row contact-card">  
                <div class="map col-5" id="map"></div>
                <div class="offset-2 image-scroll"></div>
                <div class="map-des col-3 text-white my-auto pt-4" id="m-des"></div>
                    
<!-- i struggle in this part -- >

                <!-- google reviews -->
                <div class="col-1 text-center">
                  <div id="google-icon">
                  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nknMt4k/search.png" class="google-icon">    
                </div>  
                  
    
                  <div class="side-star">
                  <p class="google-review text-nowrap">
                    <strong>Google Review</strong>
                  </p>
                  <div class="five-star d-flex flex-column">
                    
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                  
                  
                  
                  </div>
                </div></div>
```

Comment: I tried it but elements only got centered whereas the vertical margin between the elements are not like your code..

Comment: Also i want google review text and stars to be vertically centered

Comment: Is what you need is different from what you see in the snippet?

Comment: For the margins, add `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` in `#google-icon img` exactly as in the snippet